# std::make_pair with c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, raspberry-pi

Hello I have the following code:

```
bool PinManager::insertPin(const std::string& p_pinNumber, const std::string& p_mode)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<GPIOPin> pin(new GPIOPin(p_pinNumber, p_mode));
    if (pin)
    {
        m_pinsInUse.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<GPIOPin> >(p_pinNumber, pin));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code has always compiled, but when I added the `-std=c++0x` flag this code fails to compile with the message:

```
[ 42%] Building CXX object gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp.o
/home/pi/robot_2.0/trunk/gpioaccess/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp: In member function 'bool gpioaccess::PinManager::insertPin(const string&, const string&)':
/home/pi/robot_2.0/trunk/gpioaccess/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp:39:101: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(const string&, boost::shared_ptr<gpioaccess::GPIOPin>&)'
/home/pi/robot_2.0/trunk/gpioaccess/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp:39:101: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:262:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/pinmanager/pinmanager.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [gpioaccess/CMakeFiles/gpioaccess.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After doing a little digging I found that the fact this compiled before was probably a bug; however, I am still unsure how to fix this. Does anyone have any points in the correct direction?

`gcc --version` is `gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3`

Comment: `make_pair` should be able to deduce the argument types, try removing your explicit template arguments: `std::make_pair(p_pinNumber, pin)`

Comment: Side note: `if (pin)` is always true or has no effect if an exception is thrown

Comment: @melak47 That was the problem removing the arguments allowed the code to compile. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post line numbers with your code. It makes it all too hard to copy & paste it into an editor or an online-compiler form.

Comment: @DieterLücking Good catch thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) has changed between [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), it accepts parameters *by forwarding-references* rather than *by value*. This means that by specifying its type template arguments explicitly you end up with the following instantiation:

```
std::make_pair<std::string , boost::shared_ptr<GPIOPin> >
             (std::string&&, boost::shared_ptr<GPIOPin>&&);
```

expecting *rvalue* references, which cannot bind to lvalues.

You should not specify type template arguments of `std::make_pair` explicitly. Instead, you should let the compiler deduce them on its own:

```
std::make_pair(p_pinNumber, pin)
```

Additionally, since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), when using `std::map`, you can construct the pair in-place:

```
m_pinsInUse.emplace(p_pinNumber, pin);
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can utilize class template argument deduction, and construct `std::pair` without specifying class template arguments:

```
std::pair(p_pinNumber, pin)
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know. The C++14 definition has an additional change.

Comment: One should stress the point that this is indeed a *breaking* change in C++11.

Comment: In practice it's only a breaking change for dumb code that misuses `make_pair`

Comment: Upvoted for answering clearly, concisely and without sounding condescending or needlessly critical.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of `std::make_pair` is to simplify creating a `std::pair` so you don't need to specify the template arguments, letting the compiler deduce them.

If you call `std::make_pair<T, U>(t, u)` with explicit template arguments then you are defeating the entire purpose of the function, because you are preventing deduction, **and** you're wasting time typing extra characters and potentially creating unnecessary copies of objects, when you could just do `std::pair<T, U>(t, u)` instead (saving yourself from typing five extra, useless characters).

If you use `std::make_pair` the way it's intended to be used then you won't even notice that it changed in C++11. If you misuse it by pointlessly providing template arguments then it might not work in C++11, so don't do that.

I wrote a more complete explanation at http://advogato.org/person/redi/diary/239.html

Answer (score 6):

Note that in c++11 std::make_pair can often be dropped in favour of the initializer constructor

```
m_pinsInUse.insert({p_pinNumber, pin});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer @NexusSquared provided: 
you could just use the new emplace function of std::map:

m_pinsInUse.emplace(p_pinNumber, pin);

which is even shorter and constructs the std::pair inplace instead of constructing it followed by copying the contents of the newly constructed pair to the memory of the map.