# change libstdc++ to libc++ get error not matching function for call to make_pair?

Tags: c++

I want to know if the libc++ supports make_pair or have same function which I really don't know.

My project used libstdc++ before, but after update the kernel, it adopts libc++ instead of libstdc++. And make_pair get error.

```
../../qb/chrome/browser/wup/stat/wup_stat/wup_stat_8075.cc:333:1: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair'
IMPLEMENT_TYPE(Int, int)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../qb/chrome/browser/wup/stat/wup_stat/wup_stat_8075.cc:259:22: note: expanded from macro 'IMPLEMENT_TYPE'
(m_map##TYPE).insert(std::make_pair<RecordType8075, WupStat8075ReportItem<TYPE>>(item.itemKey, item));\
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/melody5417/QB3972/trunk/browser/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:493:1: note: candidate function [with _T1 = RecordType8075, _T2 = (anonymous namespace)::WupStat8075ReportItem<int>] not viable: no known conversion from 'RecordType8075' to 'RecordType8075 &&' for 1st argument
make_pair(_T1&& __t1, _T2&& __t2)
^
../../qb/chrome/browser/wup/stat/wup_stat/wup_stat_8075.cc:334:1: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair'
IMPLEMENT_TYPE(String, std::string)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../qb/chrome/browser/wup/stat/wup_stat/wup_stat_8075.cc:259:22: note: expanded from macro 'IMPLEMENT_TYPE'
(m_map##TYPE).insert(std::make_pair<RecordType8075, WupStat8075ReportItem<TYPE>>(item.itemKey, item));\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/melody5417/QB3972/trunk/browser/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:493:1: note: candidate function [with _T1 = RecordType8075, _T2 = (anonymous namespace)::WupStat8075ReportItem<std::__1::basic_string<char> >] not viable: no known conversion from 'RecordType8075' to 'RecordType8075 &&' for 1st argument
make_pair(_T1&& __t1, _T2&& __t2)
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: The macro looks broken. It seems to have been written for C++03, but badly.

Comment: Don't specify types explicitly in `make_pair`, as its [definition has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32443181/3953764)

Comment: Of course it has [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), if you read the error message a little closer you will understand that the compiler is not missing `std::make_pair`. Instead there seems to be a mismatch between C++ standard versions, as the compiler complains about conversions from `RecordType8075` to `RecordType8075 &&`.

Comment: Also, please don't post images of text. Instead copy-paste the actual text into the question. It will make it much easier for us to (for example) copy-paste parts of the text ourselves.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks for your help, especially the link.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your help and reminder, the problem is solved. Thanks~